# place objects in an array directly in different column as string in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm quite a noob when it comes to programming and google apps script. Hope someone can help me out since the headache is becoming unbearable ;)

The situation:
1 spreadsheet,
2 sheets: Sheet1 & Sheet2

in Sheet1, first column, I have my data which contains text as email plainBody.
in my code i use a regular expression to get the exact data from the e-mail that i want, this works fine.

The issue:
I'can't find a way to set the values of this result into column B of Sheet2.
I don't want to first place the results in columnA and then copy it to columnB.

Hope you guys can help me out :) I've googled my ass off but didn't find a solution..

Current code i'm using:

```
 function emailExtract(){

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //get active spreadsheet and sheetname
 var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');//get active spreadsheet and sheetname

 var rangeA = sheet2.getRange("A1:A");//range to later on set the numberFormat, not important
 var rangeB = sheet2.getRange("B1:B");//range to later on set the numberFormat, not important


 sheet2.clear();

 var ss = sheet.getDataRange();//define the range that includes data

 var values = ss.getValues();// get the values (plainBody email), 153 rows of data (at the moment).
 var regex = /\d+,\d*/; //Regular expression to extract the numbers i need.



 for (var i = 0;i < values.length;i++){

 var eurMoney = regex.exec(values[i]);//execute the regular expression on every row with data.


 sheet2.appendRow([eurMoney.toString()]);//this places the values in columnA, I need these values to appear in columnB!



 }



   rangeA.setNumberFormat("€0.00");
   rangeB.setNumberFormat("€0.00");



   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
sheet2.appendRow([eurMoney.toString()]);
```

use `getLastRow` on the data Range of sheet2 (`sheet2.getDataRange`). Then, using

```
sheet2.getRange(getLastRow+1, 2).setValue(eurMoney)
```

in place of the line you mentioned in your code. Hence, you for loop would look something like this;

```
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++)
{
  var range = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var lRow = range.getLastRow();
  sheet2.getRange(lRow+1, 2).setValue(eurMoney);
}
```

However, please note `getValues` outputs a 2 dimensional array. In your implementation, I don't believe it is being implemented correctly. So I would leave it to your better judgement to work on that.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but somehow the output of the eurMoney starts at row 2, not row one. How is that possible?

Comment: Ah don't bother, this made it work:sheet2.getRange(lRow,2, 2).setValue(money);